# UWP application rebuild instead of deploy

Tags: uwp, c++-cx

Since last Windows 10 update (current version is 1703 - OSBuild 16257.1), Every time I build my UWP application I get following error:

```
Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path 'abcd.dll'. Source files:...
```

I used to have this error before, and to solve it by building the INSTALL project generated by CMake. Then application deployment would take place right away.

Since this last update, application deployment rebuilds the whole solution again.
I tried to figure out why by looking at the build diagnostic output, but found nothing really relevant in this big chunk of data.

This is problematic as right now, I cannot deploy and launch my application.

Answer (score 0):

Actually deleting my git repo and redoing a full check out solved the issue